# Parse.com master key doesn't let to write PFUser currentUser

Tags: javascript, objective-c, parse-platform

UPDATE: In a nutshell, I would like to use the Master key, because I need to write an other user object with my current user, but I don't want to override all security, I just wanna use it in one function. The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661775/what-does-the-master-key-in-parse-cloud) gave a very nice starting point, however I couldn't make it to work. It's the last code block in this question.

---

I have two separated functions. The first is pure objective-c, it deletes users from the `currentUser`'s `firstRelation`. It worked well without any problems until i added a different CloudCode function into a different view controller. The CloudCode function uses the master key and adds `currentUser` to `otherUser`'s `sampleRelation` & adds `otherUser` to `currentUser`'s `sampleRelation` (`firstRelation` and `sampleRelation` is two different column inside the `User` class).

So the problem is when I delete a user from `currentUser`'s `firstRelation` (with current user) my app crashes, because the user must be authenticated via logIn or signUp. Actually i don't understand this, because in this case I'm writing the `currentUser` with the `currentUser` instead of another user, so it must work without any problems (and worked before the CloudCode).

I'm almost sure that it's because I'm using the master key with the CloudCode, but have no idea how can I avoid it. Everything else is still working, for example I can upload images with `currentUser`.

Here is the code that I'm using for the CloudCode, JavaScript is totally unknown for me, maybe somebody will see what causes the problem.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

userQuery.get(request.params.userId)
.then(function (user) {
    var relation = user.relation("sampleRelation");
    relation.add(request.user);
    // chain the promise
    return user.save();
}).then(function (user) {
    var currentUser = request.user;
    var relation = currentUser.relation("sampleRelation");
    relation.add(user);
    // chain the new promise
    return currentUser.save();
}).then(function () {
    response.success();
}, function (error) {
    response.error(error);
});
});
```

It crashes when i try to remove the object:

```
PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFRelation *myFriendsRel = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"simpleRelation"];

    if ([self isFriend:user]) {

        for (PFUser *friendName in self.friends) {
            if ([friendName.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]){ 
                [self.friends removeObject:friendName];
                break; // to exit a loop
            }
        }
        // remove from parse

        [myFriendsRel removeObject:user];
        NSLog(@"deleted: %@", user.username);


    }
    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

This is the newest attempt, that based Fosco's answer from the other question. It works, but the same way as the earlier versions.

```
  Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
                                   var userId = request.params.userId;

                                   var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
                                   user = new User({ objectId: userId });

                                   var currentUser = request.user;

                                   var relation = user.relation("friendsRelation");
                                   relation.add(currentUser);


                                   user.save(null, { useMasterKey:true}).then(function(user) {
                                                    response.success(user);
                                                    }, function(error) {
                                                    response.error(error)
                                                    });
                                   });
```

Comment: it's not clear where this is failing..

Comment: @Fosco sorry, i forget to add it. The added code worked well without any problems until i started using cloud code.

Comment: still not clear, at all.

Comment: @Fosco I created a function, that lets for the current user to add another user to his friends list. If current user taps the add friend button i assign `sampleUser` to his friends list (`sampleRelation`) and also assign `currentUser` to the friends list of `sampleUser`. I couldn't wrote `sampleUser`'s `sampleRelation` because of security reasons, therefore i started using Master key with CloudCode. With the new CC function i could write another user's `sampleRelation`, but it evoked another problem. I have another `PFRelation` on the user class called `firstRelation`. It's like favorites..

Comment: @Fosco The current user can add other users to this list, but he won't be added to the other users favorites. Naturally current user can delete users from this favorites list, which was already implemented before the CC function and worked well. Now it doesn't working and gives an error since I'm using the master key.

Comment: The code you have appears correct. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @RyanDuffy The problem with the last code is, that the master key is still "global". When I call the obj-c code that you can see above, the app crash with this error: `the user must be authenticated via logIn or signUp`, despite it worked well before I started using CloudCode.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance it looks like its failing because you're trying to remove an object from an array whilst it is being iterated. I know this causes a crash in Objective C regardless of whether you're using Parse objects or not.

Try re-writing this segment:

```
        for (PFUser *friendName in self.friends) {
        if ([friendName.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]){ 
            [self.friends removeObject:friendName];
            break; // to exit a loop
        }
    }
```

To something like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (PFUser *friendName in self.friends) {
        if (![friendName.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
        [tempArray addObject:friendName];
    }
    self.friends = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
```

Again, only had a quick glance so not 100% if that is your problem but it looks like it, let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I recreated the project and it worked fine, but still don't know what was the problem.