# What does the Master Key in Parse Cloud?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Could somebody explain me in brief that what does the `master key` within Parse Cloud Code?

Is it possible that a recently implemented CC function (which uses the master key) can change the behavior of other non Cloud Code functions?

As an instance, you have a properly working solution which lets to the current user to add other `PFUser` objects into a relation and delete them if needed. Until this point you don't need the `master key` because you writing the `PFUser currentUser` with the current user. Later you create another type of user relation where you want to write another `PFUser` object, now this time you need to use `master key`, because without this the `currentUser` won't be able to write another `PFUser` objects. Therefore you create a Cloud Code file to handle this issue and give legitimacy to the actual `currentUser` for writing other users. Now everything is working fine, we don't get an error when the actual user wants to write other user objects. However something happened. When `currentUser` tries to delete data from his first `PFRelation` (that was also worked before the new cc function) he gets the same error `..user must be authenticated via logIn or signUp` that we got before we first tried to write an other user.

I guess since we using the master key it will override the existing/original security options
and we need to implement it for every other function. Am i right? If yes, how should i deal with this? Or is it possible to just set different restrictions inside the `main.js` cc file, and every "old" function will work in the same way plus the new one which using master key?

I would really appreciate any information about the topic, because it's a huge black hole for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The master key overrides all security, such as ACL or Class-based permissions.  It is like the "root" password.

You should invoke it only when needed, because all methods for the current request after it is enabled with `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` will use the master key.

You can selectively use it by passing options to the individual query/save/etc methods.

```
query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) { // ...

object.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then( // ...
```

Comment: So I don't have to use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` rather I can do this `user.save(null, { useMasterKey:true}).then(function(user) { response.success(user);}, function(error) {response.error(error) });` and in this case it won't affect the whole project?

Comment: correct! :) it's much better to pass it in to the exact calls you need it, rather than enable it for everything.

Comment: Thank you Fosco, I will try it now. It's amazing to get help straight from the source.

Comment: I've updated my code and getting the same error. Do i need to reset somehow the permissions?

Comment: Where 's the then syntax from?

Comment: Is this also true using the c# SDK?  I couldn't find any place to pass the masterkey when doing queries.  Otherwise I suppose I will have to write some cloud code to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The promises syntax documentation is currently hosted at http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#promises